# How to break the solution set and join the solution sets and notations associated with them

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-set-theory

**Joining the sets:**

Suppose $\cos x\cos2x=0$

We write as following

$$\cos x=0 \text { or } \cos2x=0$$
$$x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \text { or } x=\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4} \text { where n $\in$ I }$$

Note that we are using same variable $n$ for both general solutions.

**Is it fine to use same variable $n$ for both general solutions?**

**Breaking the set** :

Suppose we have a solution set $\{0,\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\pi,\dfrac{5\pi}{4}\,\dfrac{7\pi}{4},2\pi\cdots\cdots\}$

Suppose we have to write the general term for the above solution set, so it seems difficult to write a single general term, so we dissociate it into two solution sets, $\{0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi\cdots\} \text { and } \{\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\dfrac{5\pi}{4},\dfrac{7\pi}{4}\}$

Can we write general term as $n\pi \text { and } \left(\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}\right) \text { where n $\in$ I }$

**Is it fine to use same variable $n$ for both general solutions?**

Comment: Not only is it fine, but you must, since the original equation has only one variable.

Comment: ok for the section "breaking the set", I have used same variable n, but actual solution is $k\pi,\left(\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}\right) \text {where $n \in I$ and $k \in I$} $

Comment: What I meant was both must be of the form $x=$.  You may use different indices for the integer sets.

Comment: You don't have *two* general solutions to speak of "both". You have one general solution, some of whose elements are expressed in terms of one formula, and some of whose elements are expressed in terms of the other. The actual solution is the *set* $$\left\{ \frac {(2n+1)\pi}2, \frac {(2n+1)\pi}4\ \middle |\ n \in \Bbb Z\right\}$$ This set contains the same entries as the set $$\left\{ \frac {(2n+1)\pi}2, \frac {(2k+1)\pi}4\ \middle |\ n \in \Bbb Z, k \in  \Bbb Z\right\}$$(The conventional symbol for the set of integers is $\Bbb Z$. $I$ is commonly used for generic index sets.)

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to write your solution as a union of two sets
$$
\left\{\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \mid n \in \Bbb{Z} \right\} \cup \left\{\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4} \mid n \in \Bbb{Z} \right\}
$$
but if you want to avoid the union, you could write this set as follows
$$
\left\{\frac{n\pi}{4} \mid n \in \Bbb{Z} \text{ and } n \not\equiv 0 \bmod 4 \right\} 
$$